# How to set replace command if dynamic target in anchor tag

Tags: java, android

This is my Html

```
desc=<a target="_blank" href="http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=">A. P. (DIR Series) Circular No. 46 dated June 14, 2005</a>

String   k = replace ( desc, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&amp;id=35000000000000001648&amp;search=\">", "");
```

In desc I'm getting HTML I have replace command 
I have to remove link so I'm pick data from anchor tag target is dynamic where id varies I'm able to replace linking to text whose target is

http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&id=35000000000000001648&search=\

but when ever target changes, I mean to say if id changes, it doesn't replace link as text.

Please tell me how to get and set the id values so that if target will be dynamic we can replace link as text. I'm new to android programming.

Answer (score 0):

try this: you can extract id by using `indexOf` from string and then find `substring`.like:

```
   String str = "http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=";
    int indexoff = str.indexOf("id=");
    int indexofl = str.indexOf("&amp;search=");
    String strsub="";
    if(indexoff !=-1 && indexofl !=-1)
     {
      strsub = str.substring(indexoff + 3, indexofl - indexoff - 3);
     }
    String strstaticstring = "http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=" + strsub + "&amp;search=";
    String k = desc.replace(strstaticstring, "");
```

Comment: hii i have implemented But here /corporate/  also changes some time it comes directtaxlaw

Comment: ok then update your question with all possibilities then i will see but in question u have say only id is changing dynamically

Comment: u have posted new question and what abut this question accept it

Comment: actlly in privious quetsion only  id was varying now here id and coprporate  also varies so i have posted for that

Comment: Dear fend still same Exception is coming can i send you complete code??

Comment: first update your question with full code if not get solved then u will send me.